# Dual national planning a visit to the US

Tags: canada

We are a Canadian-Iranian family, residing in the UAE. We have recently attended a family event in Iran with our Iranian passports. We are planning our US trip a week after our visit in Toronto. We would be entering the US through the Canadian border (Pearson Airport). Do we need to obtain a US visa?